# Why `text-align: center` in flex broke layout after resizing down and up?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have problem with `text-align: center` and `flex`.

Here is [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-mendeleev-3mrkt) I separated out of my current project to look into this problem:

While it is wide `>940px window width` it looks fine and after it drop bellow `940px`, it changes to the other layout - no problems so far.

The problem is, after sizing up back to wider, it stays broken ;_;

I don't understand why it behave that way.

1. It looks nice,
   [image: It looks nice,]
2. After sizing down too (using other layout)
   [image: After sizing down too (using other layout))]
3. But it does not come back to 1) step after resizing up
   [image: But it does not come back to 1) step after resizing up]

Progress:

- I discovered through testing that disabling and enabling `text-align: center` make it look fine again (using devtools). Maybe it's some rendering bug and re-adding positioning style (as `text-align`) make it rerender whole part?
- I tried using `display: none` when it is `<940px`, but it does not help. I don't think it's related to the other layout (one used `<940px`.

Comment: Im not sure that you need `text-align`, it could be better and more straightforward to use `align-items`, and `justify-items`, this are meant to work well with flex

Comment: This `text-align` is used only to align text inside buttons in fact. It does not matter. It also brokes without it after resizing up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed this and within the breakpoints and it doesn't break like before. Are you referring to this behavior?

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items:center;
flex-direction: row;
```